# Dual boot Ubuntu and Batorcera

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bash, permissions

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a 9500hx SBC, everything is up to date and upgraded so let's get right into the issue.

I am adding a menu entry for Batocera through Ubuntu Grub (NOT using Grub-customizer nor any other third-party tools); however, I am receiving an error message: Device not found.

I attempted to use Batocera's walkthrough which stated to simply use Grub.d/50_Batocera and that sudo update-grub will grab the new custom entry which is provided by batocera as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF
menuentry "batocera.linux" {
      search --set=root --label BATOCERA
      linux /boot/linux label=BATOCERA console=tty3 quiet loglevel=0 vt.global_cursor_default=0
      initrd /boot/initrd.gz
}
EOF"
```

However, as most of you can already see, this is missing the Exec tail code AND the CAT << EOF will cause an error message with unrecognized syntax. The Spock in me is like "...Highly illogical Captain". So I cut the code to Just the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
menuentry "batocera.linux" {
      search --set=root --label BATOCERA
      linux /boot/linux label=BATOCERA console=tty3 quiet loglevel=0 vt.global_cursor_default=0
      initrd /boot/initrd.gz
}
```

However, I received the error no device found BATOCERA; upon returning to Ubuntu I confirmed the Volumes label is indeed BATOCERA as it was a default installation and no custom names nor relabeling occurred. My Dr.Mccoy sense tingling "I'm just a country doctor, not a Linux Wizard!!" but I consulted with my inner neck-beard and instead decided to use the UUDI and be done with, Code as Follows:

```
menuentry "batocera.linux" {
       search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ####-####
       linux /boot/linux root=UUID=####-#### console=tty3 quiet loglevel=0
       initrd /boot/initrd.gz
}
```

I removed the Label specification as Grub did not find the volumes label initially; However, I received the SAME error message Error: No such Device: ####-####. i am now sort of at a loss.

I reviewed the Boot/linux location and found that my permissions are frozen at `-rw-r--r--` so I thought perhaps I was missing Execute so I `sudo chown USER:GROUP -R /Directory/to/BATOCERA` (-R means Recursive to ensure all subsidiary folders and files receive the same ownership updates) and then `sudo chmod -R 741 /Directory/to/BATOCERA` (New Linux users see notes below for context on permissions). But I am still receiving the same Error message and I have noted that my permissions to the `/boot/linux` folder within Batocera have not changed and are still 644 instead of 741; however, the community does not seem to be having this issue so I am not sure what's going on. Scotty on my shoulder screaming "I'm given all she's got cap'in! I Can'ny give'ya any more!"

But then my Goerdi Laforge kicked in and I tried for a third attempt; I used the Existing Grub.d/40_Custom entry again with Both the Label code AND UUID only to receive the same error messages! And I'm witnessing the Borg "Resistance is futile" moment. . .

So finally, after seething with the fury of a Sith lord watching a peaceful republic and not having unlimited power nor control over the senate, I decided to add the entry directly into the `Grub.cfg` like an absolute deranged madman on a savage Friday night tear.

I see my GAMES drive (aka BATOCERA AKA Batorcera.linux) and I click the entry...... Error: No Such Device: UUID.... the rage in me bordered on pure elation of ecstasy and belligerently indiscriminate hate that only the Hulk could truly understand. Using all of my will not to destroy my monitor and PC I revert to Dr.Banner and rethink my strategy... my Gandalf has no power here

Any Assistance from the Counsel of Ricks would be greatly appreciated!

(For new Linux users the total number 7 is the sum of the following permissions: Read(r)=4 Write(w)=2 Execute(x)=1 Total =7. The first number is the root, the second number is the user, and the third number is others so 741 means RWX for root, RW for users, and X for all others. this is a numerical value for the Written format which is as follows -rw-r--r-- meaning the Root user can Read(r) and Write(w) but not Execute as there is a - instead of an x; the user can Read(r) but not Write(w) nor Execute(x) as both are replaced with the - values, and all others can only Read(r) but not Write(w) nor Execute(x) for the same reason previously discussed)

Comment: Thank you for the Reply User535733 but as i already stated i double checked the Label and UUIDs... they are correct, label is batocera and my UUID is accurate; unless you're suggesting i switch to the PARTUUID?